# Column space in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking to get some help with the following problem. Given matrix $A$ and vector $c$. Is vector $c$ in the coumn space of $A$? And if so why?

Matrix $A$

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2  \\
3 & 4  \\
5 & 6  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

vector c:
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
2 \\ 
3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: thank you for the edit. I will use that format from now on. Any idea of how to solve this problem I have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Calculation**

You can create an augmented matrix with the columns being the three vectors: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\3&4&2\\5&6&3\end{bmatrix}$$ and then row reduce, getting
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&\frac{1}{2}\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
From there, we see $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ are the numbers to multiply the vector by; double checking, $$0\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\5\end{bmatrix}+\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\6\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\6\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$$
Yes, this is correct. So yes, vector $c$ is in the column space of $A$.

**Theory**

Remember here that we just want to check if there is some scalar that we can multiply by each of the *column vectors* (remember, these are the individual columns of the matrix $A$) that when these new vectors are added up, it equals the vector we are wondering about; i.e.:
$$x_1(v_1)+x_2(v_2)+...+x_n(v_n)=c$$
This is the general equation, where you are trying to figure out if there is a coefficient that will give $c$. In this case, there is, and so $c$ is in the column space of $A$.

Further, you can remember that column space is the *span of the linear combinations of the column vectors* which again can be represented as the equation above, where $x_1$ through $x_n$ can be any number.

Hope this helps!

Comment: why did you row reduce to get that matrix? what does that matrix show us

Comment: do you choose the number after the leading 1 in each row to multiple the column vector by?

Comment: @linalg, row reducing here is the exact same principle as it is for solving a system of linear equations. You simplify so that you can see easily what to multiply each individual vector by - it solves the equation. And yes, the number after the leading 1 in each row is what you multiply the column vector by.

Comment: awesome thanks for your time

Comment: perfect explanation

Comment: @linalg, no problem, glad to help. =)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 6\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Column space of $A$ is just the set generated by the linear combinations of columns of $A$, which is equivalent to asking if there is some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$a\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 5\end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 4 \\ 6\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Notice that if we choose $a = 0, b = \frac{1}{2}$ we get?